# How do services like Firebase and Now from ZEIT generate domains?

Tags: domain, domain-name

When you deploy a web app or site to Firebase or ZEIT Now they give you a generated domain. They give an option to add a custom domain if you want it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain 
All of the Firebase domains seem to have www.somename.firebaseapp.com and ZEIT has this form www.somename.now.sh/
My specific question is how could I generate these "throw away" domains to use with private services I run on my own hardware?

Comment: They use a wildcard dns record and check in their datavase on the server side to lookup the page.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a base to do further research. From the Wikipedia page I found from Googling "wildcard dns" it looks like the answer.

Comment: You're welcome! I will publish as an answer the second I have access to a computer

Comment: Sounds good, I normally check this family of sites every few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services such as ZEIT Now and Firebase store their domains as data on the server side, and check the domain manually when you browse to such a page.

On the DNS side, they use a [wildcard DNS entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record), thus freeing them to use any subdomain that they want.

For reference, this is how stackexchange.com can display an error when you browse to an invalid site, like so
[image]

(for blind people, the screenshot shows an SE controlled error page with TLS/SSL instead of a DNS error from the browser)